# Check positivity with additional conditions

Tags: assumptions

I am completely new to Mathematica. I would like to check when
$$
\frac{1}{2ka}\left(\sqrt{b}x-\frac{z}{\sqrt{b}}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2mb}\left(\sqrt{a}y-\frac{z}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2c}(bx+ay-z)^2-\frac{bx^2}{2mb}-\frac{ay^2}{2kb}
$$
is positive under the conditions that
$$
x,y,z\geq 0,\qquad a,b,c>0,\qquad k,m>0,\qquad \frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{m}=1,\qquad a\cdot b = c.
$$

I have tried

```
A= (1/(2ka)) (Sqrt[b]x-(1/Sqrt[b])z)^2+(1/(2mb))(Sqrt[a]y-(1/Sqrt[a])z)^2+(1/(2c))(bx+ay-z)^2-(b/(2m))(x^2/a)-(a/(2k))(y^2/b)
```

and then

```
Positive[A, Assumptions -> x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && a >0 && b >0 && c >0 && k > 0 && m > 0 && 1/k + 1/m ==1 && a*b==c]
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. `ak` is a symbol. `a k` is the product of two variables. Please make all such corrections. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Reduce can check

```
expr = (1/(2 k*a))  (Sqrt[b] x - (1/Sqrt[b]) z)^2 + (1/(2 m*
       b)) (Sqrt[a] y - (1/Sqrt[a]) z)^2 + (1/(2*c)) (b*x + a*y - 
      z)^2 - (b/(2*m)) (x^2/a) - (a/(2*k)) (y^2/b)
assume = 
 x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && k > 0 && 
  m > 0 && 1/k + 1/m == 1 && a*b == c

Reduce[expr > 0 && assume]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See help for examples

[image]